# Visualization of rectangles in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-visualization, visualization

So, I have a 10x10 grid. Any ideas about how to visualize 2025 rectangles in it?
I mean, I want to put them on one page (maybe a picture), but I don't know which library should I use.
I want to visualize all with maybe alphas, like when more border above each other I want to visualize that too. I mean I have no idea how to do that. I don't need to give me code or anything, I only want a library name to use.

**EDIT:**
My rectangles are defined in a list with 4 tuples in it one tuple has the x,y coordinate of a corner like:`[(x, y), (x2, y), (x, y2), (x2, y2)]`

**EDIT2:**
Now my code is:

```
multipler = 100
canvasH = 10 * multipler  # 10 == Y in squares.py
canvasW = 10 * multipler  # 10 == X in squares.py

img = numpy.zeros((canvasH, canvasW, 3), numpy.uint8)
# img = cv2.line(img, (0, 0), (511, 511), (255, 0, 0), 5)

rectangles = [[(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 2), (1, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 3), (1, 3)]...]

for rectangle in rectangles:
    cv2.rectangle(img, (rectangle[0][0] * multipler, rectangle[0][1] * multipler), (rectangle[3][0] * multipler, rectangle[3][1] * multipler), (206, 220, 242))

cv2.imshow('img', img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But I only see `9x9` pics, so I can't see all of them (I have 2025).

Thanks,
Marci

Comment: you could possibly use `opencv`

Comment: How are your rectangles defined ?

Comment: Do you want the rectangles to be filled? Or only showing the edges? Are all rectangles with integer coordinates? How can you see something with so many rectangles with the same color all over eachother?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of unknowns in your question. Here is a possible interpretation.

Some remarks:

- Many libraries exist to draw rectangles. Matplotlib is used a lot for visualizations and has a convenient [`Rectangle`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html) function.
- There exist many representations for colors, e.g. by 3 values between 0 and 1 for red-green-blue (more info [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/colors/colors.html)).
- The alpha can either be incorporated as a 4th element, or given separately.
- If you only want to see the edges, set the facecolor to 'none'.
- There is no need to scale the values. Libraries such as matplotlib do this automatically via setting the dpi (dots-per-inch, standard values: 100, 300, 600)
- If you want to use the result not just on the screen, `savefig` can save to many formats. '.png' is most suitable for a pure image format. '.svg' is interesting for a high quality vector format.
- The end result now looks like an abstract painting, but can serve as a starting point for exploring.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import random

rectangles = []
for _ in range(2025):
    x = random.uniform(0.0, 10.0)
    y = random.uniform(0.0, 10.0)
    w = random.uniform(0.1, 1.0)
    h = random.uniform(0.1, 1.0)
    rectangles.append([(x,y), (x+w,y), (x,y+h), (x+w,y+h)])

color = [c/256 for c in (206, 220, 242)] # rgb values between 0 and 1
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
ax.set(xlim=(0, 10), ylim=(0, 10))
ax.axis('off')

for rectangle in rectangles:
    xy = rectangle[0]
    width = rectangle[3][0] - rectangle[0][0]
    height = rectangle[3][1] - rectangle[0][1]
    rect = Rectangle(xy, width, height, linewidth=1, edgecolor='none', facecolor=color, alpha=0.3)
    ax.add_patch(rect)

plt.savefig("test.png", bbox_inches='tight', dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting image]

PS1: For your additional question in the remarks about many rectangles overlapping on a grid, you might draw an image colored by the number of rectangles that cover each unit square. Some example code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

rectangles = [[(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 2), (1, 2)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 3), (1, 3)],
              [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 4), (1, 4)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 5), (1, 5)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 6), (1, 6)],
              [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 7), (1, 7)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 8), (1, 8)], [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 9), (1, 9)],
              ... ]

grid = [[0 for y in range(10)] for x in range(10)]
for r in rectangles:
    for x in range(r[0][0], r[3][0] + 1):
        for y in range(r[0][1], r[3][1] + 1):
            grid [x][y] += 1

plt.imshow(grid, cmap='magma_r')
plt.show()
```

PS2: For your example with almost all rectangles with integer coordinates on a grid of 10x10, an idea is to only draw the edges, use random colors to differentiate and move all points randomly, so they don't overlap anymore. Even then there is still a huge amount of almost overlapping rectangles.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from matplotlib import cm
import random

rectangles = ...

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
ax.set(xlim=(0, 11), ylim=(0, 11))
ax.axis('off')
cmap = cm.get_cmap('rainbow')
for rectangle in rectangles:
    x0 = rectangle[0][0] + random.uniform(-.45, .45)
    y0 = rectangle[0][1] + random.uniform(-.45, .45)
    x1 = rectangle[3][0] + random.uniform(-.45, .45)
    y1 = rectangle[3][1] + random.uniform(-.45, .45)
    width = x1-x0
    height = y1-y0
    rect = Rectangle((x0, y0), width, height, linewidth=1,
                     facecolor='none', edgecolor=cmap(random.uniform(0,1)), alpha=0.5)
    ax.add_patch(rect)
plt.savefig("test.png", bbox_inches='tight', dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is this answer helpful?

Comment: Yes, it Was! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Right, so I have another issue.
I have another datafile: https://pastebin.com/8S3AWDXc
And, the picture I get is: https://imgur.com/a/ResakBI

Comment: What is the issue? What do you expect to get? Maybe a scatter plot makes more sense? Or only draw the outline of the rectangles leaving the inner part blank? What is the significance of your rectangles?

Comment: I just want a good visualization of them. To like, see each one of them. Can't I solve this?